# Deploy from Tomcat text interface fails Invalid context path null was specified

Tags: linux, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I have an apparently simple situation: a running Tomcat 7.0.54 instance whose host is configured with `autoDeploy=false` and `unpackWars=true` and I want to deploy a new web application there without restarting the server.

From within the server machine I copied the webapp WAR file to the Tomcat `appBase` directory (`webapps/`), then from the HTML manager I can succesfully deploy it from the "Deploy directory or WAR file located on server" section by only filling the "Context path" form field and hitting "Deploy".

I'm now trying  to do the same from the command line, and while commands such as:

```
 curl -u admin:password1 http://localhost:8680/manager/text/list
```

and:

```
curl -u admin:password1 http://localhost:8680/manager/text/stop?path=/webapp
```

Both give `OK - [...]`, I can't find any syntax for the `/deploy` command that would succeed, any attempt results in the following error:

```
FAIL - Invalid context path null was specified
```

According to the [manager docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_a_Directory_or_War_from_the_Host_appBase), the following syntax should do it:

```
curl -u admin:password1 http://localhost:8680/manager/text/deploy?war=webapp.war
```

But it doesn't, and even adding a `&path=/webapp` parameter doesn't yield a different result.

Permissions on the `webapps/` folder are already right: as other webapps already deployed and running, everything belongs to `root`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there were two issues:

1. Being on Linux, the `&` was parsed as a job control and the command ran in the background, so I had to put the whole URL between quotes;
2. The whole working syntax is:

   ```
   http://localhost:8680/manager/text/deploy?war=webapp&path=/webapp"
   ```